# Can't get current entry's ID - Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a null variable

Tags: templating, craft3

I'm trying to upgrade my website to Craft 3 and can't resolve one issue with this piece of code:

```
{% for category in craft.categories.group('blogCategories').order('title') %}
   <li><a href="{{ category.url }}" class="button {{ entry.blogCategory.one().id == category.id ? 'light': 'primary' }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I get the following error:

> Twig Runtime Error – Twig\Error\RuntimeError
>   Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a null variable.

I can't find any information in *Changes in Craft 3*, but I bet there's a new way of getting the category ID of the current post and the `entry.blogCategory.one().id` won't work anymore?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it came out that the post I used for testing wasn't assigned to any category and that was causing the exception.

I added a validation for checking if the category is defined:

```
{{ (entry.blogCategory.one().id is defined and entry.blogCategory.one().id is not null) and entry.blogCategory.one().id == category.id ? 'light': 'primary' }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
```